# How to restore previous activity actions on Notification Click

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, android-notifications, restore

I have an Activity that is performing some download function. The activity will pop up a progress dialog and disable user interaction while downloading as well as create a notification progress.

I want the user to be able to click on the notification and return the user to the activity that has the dialog showing the progress and disabled user interaction (basically what happens when the user goes to the home screen and then reopens the app).

My current attempts seem to relaunch the activity, download still occurring, but dialog is gone and user interaction is disabled. How can I fix this?

My approaches:

set intent action

```
private static void buildNotification()
{
    //create intent  for onClick
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(activity,  activity.GetType());
    resultIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionMain);
    resultIntent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryLauncher);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(activity, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

    //set builder

    builder.SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    notificationManager = activity.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
}
```

set intent flags

```
private static void buildNotification()
{
    //create intent  for onClick
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(activity,  activity.GetType());
    resultIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop | ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(activity, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

    //set builder

    builder.SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    notificationManager = activity.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up putting just `SingleTop` flag on the intent. Hopefully this helps someone:

```
private static void buildNotification()
{
        //create intent  for onClick
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(activity, activity.GetType());
    resultIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(activity, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

    //set builder

    builder.SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    notificationManager = activity.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
}
```

By the way I'm using Xamarin.Android